# PowerPC Inline Assembly: Load C Value into Register

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, powerpc

Using `GCC` and `inline assembly`, I want to load an immediate into a specific register `r0`. However, I'm not getting the right results.

```
unsigned short value = 0x1337;

asm volatile
(
"li 0, %0\n\t"
        "sc\n\t"
        "blr"
: /* Output registers */
:"r"(value) /* Input registers */
: /* No clobbered registers */
);
```

When compiled, this gives

```
li        r0, 9
sc
blr
```

Where does the `9` come from? I wanted the specified value `0x1337` instead. [Here](https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) is a tutorial I looked at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

9 is the register containing `0x1337`, which is exactly what you asked for.  Notice how `value` is an input register? 9, a.k.a. r9, is a perfectly valid input register. This is the assembly output I get.

```
    li 9,4919
    li 0, 9
    sc
    blr
```

If you want to load 0x1337 as an immediate, just use that instead.

```
asm volatile (
    "li 0, 0x1337\n\t"
    "sc\n\t"
    "blr"
);
```

Or, just use the `"i"` constraint instead of the `"r"` constraint.

```
asm volatile (
    "li 0, %0\n\t"
    "sc\n\t"
    "blr"
    :
    : "i"(0x1337)
);
```

Comment: Yep, unsurprisingly that was a simple solution

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza: Use `gcc -mregnames` to get register names that aren't bare numbers, so you can't mix up registers and immediates.  Also, make sure you tell the compiler about any registers you clobber, and use `asm goto` to tell it you're jumping.  Although I'm not sure there is a safe way to tell the compiler your asm needs the return address in `lr` and that it returns.  You should probably write your whole function in asm, because I don't see how this can work if it inlines.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, that's the whole function. :)

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza: Then you should put a label inside the inline asm, and put the asm statement at the global scope, instead of putting it inside a C function.  Otherwise you need to stop that C function from inlining with `__attribute__((noinline))`, which kind of defeats the purpose of inline asm.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza: Or you could keep the function and get rid of the `blr`… which is redundant anyway.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Last time I checked, you can still mix up registers and immediates with `-mregnames` because the register names are just assembly macros. It does make it more obvious when humans are reading the code, though.